# How to delay Real Time Compilation of Visual Studio 2017 in my code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am working on an Open Source Project based on C# using Visual Studio 2017. Whenever I make any changes in it, Visual Studio (in a delay of about half a second) starts checking the code for errors in it which is why sometimes it gets hanged. I want to know if there is any option to increase this delay. If the delay would have been of about 3 - 5 seconds, I could make changes without any error list generated. I don't want to disable this awesome feature, but it is irritating if you don't have a great typing speed. Any solution?

Comment: VS Error Checks happen in background threads so it shouldnt/wouldnt stop you typing the code. I guess you have a Resource bottleneck in your system (Guessing this is on your Work/Office PC). Check Antivirus scans or RAM/CPU spikes when such things happen.